# When is __all__ used while importing a module in Python?

Tags: python, module, package

Say there is a greetings module like this:

```
__all__ = []

def offer(func):
   __all__.append(func.__name__)
   return func

@offer
def spanish():
   return "Hola!"

@offer
def japanese():
   return "Konnichiwa"
```

When does the interpreter decide what to import when `from greetings import *` is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When does the interpreter decide what to import when from greetings
> import * is run?

When you say `from greetings import *`, interpreter loads and executes the greeting module, then it references the objects mentioned in the `__all__` list back into the current module's global namespace so that you can access them using those symbols inside the `__all__`.

I think you guessed because you defined `__all__` at the beginning of the module and it's empty, nothing is going to be imported. No that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

`__all__` tells a list of module names that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered.

For Example,
If `__all__` is not defined, the statement `from greetings.languages import *` does not import all submodules from the package `greetings.languages` into the current namespace; it only ensures that the package `greetings.languages` has been imported (possibly running any initialization code in `__init__.py`) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package.

Comment: I think the OP knows about what `__all__` does and wants to know *when* that variable is coming into play in the importing process.